# an unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have this problem in Razor Page:
[image: Exception]

My OnPost:

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return Page();
        //TODO Add Permission
        Role.IsDelete = false;
        int roleId = _permissionService.AddRole(Role);
        return RedirectToPage("Index");
    }
```

My method:

```
public int AddRole(Role role)
    {
        _context.Roles.Add(role);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return role.RoleId;
    }
```

and MyTable:

```
[Key]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد کنید!!!")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "{0} نمیتواند بیشتر از {1} کاراکتر باشد!!!")]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public bool IsDelete { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is there any method in the code you posted with a parameter ``value``?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You could improve your question by including more details along with the code, and by making sure your image is correctly formatted to display.   Better yet: don't use an image to communicate the error. Instead paste in the text of the error (and format it as code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the `DisplayAttribute.Name` to an empty string - the error itself is a *bit* misleading, because it is not `null`, but instead it is checking with `string.IsNullOrEmpty` [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/ValidationContext.cs,183)

So either set that to a non-empty string or remove the attribute altogether (no point having it without a value, hence the exception!) and it should work.

As an aside, you should read the stack trace from your exceptions, not just the message - it gives context and a concrete place to start looking for the problem.

Comment: Whyyyyyyyy i dont see Display ;((( 
Thanks You Man For You Help <3